# elasticsearch 6 not allowing multiple types when trying to pipeline with mongo-connector

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I am trying to push data from mongodb3.6 to elasticsearch6.1 using mongo-connector.
 My records are:

```
db.administrators.find({}).pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5701d81893dc484c812b4fc1"),
        "name" : "Test Naupada",
        "username" : "adminn",
        "ward" : "56a6129f44fc869f215fe3fe",
        "password" : "nadmin"
}

rs0:PRIMARY> db.sub_ward_master.find({}).pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56a6129f44fc869f215fe3fe"),
        "wardCode" : "3",
        "wardName" : "Naupada",
        "wardgeoCodes" : [],
        "cityName" : "thane"
}
```

When I run mongo-connector I am getting following error:

```
OperationFailed: (u'1 document(s) failed to index.', [{u'index': {u'status': 400, u'_type': u'administrators', u'_index': u'smartjn', u'error': {u'reason': u'Rejecting mapping update to [smartjn] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [sub_ward_master, administrators]', u'type': u'illegal_argument_exception'}, u'_id': u'5701d81893dc484c812b4fc1', u'data': {u'username': u'adminn', u'ward': u'56a6129f44fc869f215fe3fe', u'password': u'nadmin', u'name': u'Test Naupada'}}}
```

Any help any one?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES 6 does not allow to create [more than one type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html) in any single index.

There's an [open issue](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/issues/770) in the mongo-connector repo to support ES 6. Until that's solved, you should go with ES 5 instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Val!!

Comment: it seems some of the data from mongodb which worked quite well with es2.3 , is not being pulled in properly by es5 . Looks like they need to re-tuned

Comment: Yes much probably.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in ES6 by creating a new index for different document type (ie different collection in mongoDB) and use -g flag to direct it to new index.

For example:

```
mongo-connector -m localhost:27017 -t localhost:9200 -d elastic2_doc_manager -n {db}.{collection_name} -g {new_index}.{document_type}.
```

Refer [mongo-connector-wiki](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/wiki/Configuration-Options)

Comment: To create a new index use following curl commands: 1) curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/{new_index}
2) curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/{new_index}
3) curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/{new_index}/_refresh